# Returning to usage's location after Intellij IDEA "Create on Usage" intention action

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I type a Java method call with an argument that I intend to make into a field:

```
knownObject.knownMethod(newField);
```

At this point, `newField` is highlighted as compilation error. I can press Alt+Enter and select "Create Filed 'newField'" from the menu.

That brings me up to the beginning of the class file where other fields are defined.

I can press Enter to confirm the new field's type.

Now I'd like to go back to my `knownMethod()` call and continue coding. How do I do that?

Bonus question: in the above situation, Ctrl+Shift+Backspace may help because I just edited the the `knownMethod()` call. What if I decide to first type in multiple arguments to the method? How do I get back to the argument I've just created a field for in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For getting back to a previous caret location the `Navigate > Back` menu item usually works (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> on Windows). Another option may be to use `Edit > Find > Find Usages` on the field (enable the `Skip results tab with one usage` checkbox setting)